Truss-braced wing and variable geometry
Reading about variable geometries, swing wings, rearward or forward sweep, oblique wing designs pro and cons, and Truss-braced wing designs, are there studies or experiments involving truss-braced wings and variable geometry?
One of the main disadvantage of oblique wing being maybe the pitch-roll coupling, and one of the main disadvantage of swing wing being displacement of center of lift with relation to center of gravity, using structural properties of truss-braced wing by having pivot points on each half-wing located somewhere at each half-wing individual center of lift might mitigate those issues. (probably adding new issues too)


@RobertDiGiovanni im not sure i understand. If the strut slides at the bottom, it's another variable geometry hinged at wing root like F14. Here instead the strut is static, and wing root somewhat slides in upper fuselage.

It's a matter of geometry.  Scale up the drawing and see what happens to the length of the mount points.  It would be possible to slide the wing mounts forward and have the truss pivot on either side.
